# Storage Recommendations for Hyper-v cluster on Server 2016

Tags: hyper-v, storage, windows-server-2016, cluster-shared-volumes

We have purchased a new set of 5 HP servers and an all solid state 16gb fibre Nimble storage system to replace our aged existing hardware, however, the decision was made above my head to switch from VMware to Hyper-V for the hyper-visor. I haven't used Hyper-V since just after it originally came out. So far it's been easy to figure out but one thing I'm still not sure on is how to configure the storage.

Is cluster shared volumes still the best way to utilise fibre storage in a hyper-v cluster or with the latest updates to Hyper-V is the direct attached or virtual fibre controller methods preferred now?

Comment: What does Nimble Storage support recommend?

Comment: 16gb is not a storage system, it is a low end SSD card. Do you bother doing some RTFM? Read the what is new section - Storage Spaces Direct. Can the Storage expose ISCSI? If yes - One LUN, Cluster the machines, use a CSV (CLuster SHared Volume) and put the files on it.

Comment: @TomTom I have done extensive research on the subject but as with many things it depends too much on the given situation and as such getting a clear answer is hard. I don't know what you mean in the first part of your comment. The storage system has fibre connectivity rated at 16Gb, it is not iSCSI capable. Sorry, I thought that was clear.

Comment: That shouls also work. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_Shared_Volumes - you can put it on Fibre. That is about the best you can do. Next step up would be storage spaces direct (preferably with local discs - 16gigabi sound amazing but is actually quite low end compared to what you get on a local disc backbone - 2 SAS cables have 48 gigabit, iirc).

Comment: @TomTom Thanks. Storage spaces direct looks impressive, maybe we'll look at that next time, or whatever the next best thing is. The fibre will certainly outperform our current 1Gb iSCSI system though! Looks like CSV is the way to go for now, but will consult the vender as suggested above.

Comment: That is because 1gb is SERIOUSLY pathetic. YOu are aware that you can get SSD drives today that run 30 gigabit? And that there are computer cases with place for like 20++ of them? (and yes, SuperMicro has multi nvm cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full Disclosure.  I am a Nimble Storage employee.  You will find a [Hyper-V Best Practices guide](https://infosight.nimblestorage.com/InfoSight/media/cms/active/bpg_nimble_storage_hyperv.pdf) on InfoSight.  You can also find discussions of Hyper-V on our community, [NimbleConnect](https://connect.nimblestorage.com).

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your answer suggests a workable solution to the question is available via another website. The Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites [generally frowns on this type of answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) and consider revising your answer to include the steps required to resolve the issue. And don't forget to take the [site tour](http://serverfault.com/tour).